# How do I link to the homepage from a node?

Tags: navigation

I used to had a logo provided by a theme which automatically linked to the home page. But now I replaced this with a custom block. How do I link to the homepage from that custom content type?

Using php in the block code is not an option because of caching.

Comment: You mean to say that you had a LOGO which is provided by the theme. When ever you click it from some Content type it will redirect to HOME PAGE. Now you have replaced the OLD logo with the NEW BLOCK and your are not able to redirect to HOME PAGE. Are you want LINK to redirect? Can you provide more details, if possible share image too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a link to the path `/` (slash with nothing else).
That will take the user to the homepage.